# Partition a set into k groups

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Lets say we have a set S of n integers. We divide it into k disjoint blocks of varying sizes. Also, Union of all the blocks is the whole set S. Say, the sum of elements of blocks be b1,b2,b3,.....,bk. How to minimize :

***sumof [abs(bi-bj)]***     ,   for all 1 <= i < j <= k.

Comment: Put all the elements into block `k`, so `bk` is the sum of all the elements (call it `total`) and `sumof[bi-bj]` is either `0` or `-total` for each pair, for a grand total of `-(n-1)*total`? Or did you mean the sum of _absolute_ differences?

Comment: You could make this a sort of repeated bin packing problem, trying to pack each "bin" with exactly/as close to as possible `total/n` worth of elements.

Comment: @GauravArora What did you try?